# How do I setup an email account in Evolution?

Tags: evolution, email, setup

help to activate evolution email - to receive my centurylink emails.

Comment: I made my answer more general for broader audience. Details for centurylink can be found e.g. [here](http://biz.centurylink.net/files/embarq/support/EmailPrograms/thunderbird_biz.php)

Answer (score 4):

Before we are able to setup an account with Evolution we need to know a few details on your account setting that you need to ask from your provider:

- Email address
- Username for login
- Password for login
- Account type: [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) or [POP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol)
- Name of the server for incoming mail (e.g. `imap.provider.com`)
- Name of the server for outgoing mail (e.g. `smtp.provider.com`)
- support for encryption yes/no

With these informations we can setup an account in Evolution (and similarly in other e-mail applications)

### Running Evolution for the first time

When running Evolution for the first time a setup assistant will guide you through the setting up your first account. Enter your email address in this menu:

[image]

Then enter the server name for incoming mail if it's an **IMAP** account:

[image]

**or** enter the server name for incoming mail if it's a **POP3** account:

[image]

In the same window we need to define settings for encryption (if supported):

[image]

Next we need to tell Evolution options for incoming mail:

[image]

Thenafter we need to give details on the server for outgoing mail (SMTP) (including details on authentication to this server, ask you provider if you don't know):

[image]

In the last window we can define a name how this account will be displayed in Evolution:

[image]

### Adding an account or editing account settings

In case we have Evolution already setup we can add a new account or change account setting by opening *Edit -> Preferences* and either selecting an exisitinng account to <kbd>Edit</kbd> or to <kbd>Add</kbd> a new account:

[image]

In the first tab we may enter our personal account details:

[image]

The second tab *Receiving Email* makes setting for incoming mail (see also above):

[image]

Last we need to give the details for *Sending Email*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Evolution uses a very standard way to configure email. Centurylink is completely unknown to me and I don't think any email client will have any special wizards for it, like most do for Gmail and the like. When you start Evolution for the first time, you will be presented with a configuration wizard to setup your account. You do need to know the servernames, port numbers and encryption methods that the mailserver uses, and you'll have to ask the provider (centurylink) for that information.

You provide very little information in your question, so it's difficult to know exactly what you find difficult and therefore, it's difficult to provide a very detailed answer.